# Hadoop namenode not working on OSX (ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied)

Tags: hadoop

I'm running Hadoop 1.2.1 on OSX (single-node cluster mode), and everything seems to be working except the namenode: When I run start-all.sh, the namenode fails to run. This can be seen when running stop-all.sh:

```
$ bin/stop-all.sh 
stopping jobtracker
localhost: stopping tasktracker
no namenode to stop
localhost: stopping datanode
localhost: stopping secondarynamenode
```

I've been troubleshooting this for quite a while, and I can't seem to figure out the issue--I have no idea what is causing this permission error. I've reformatted the namenode and run chmod -R 777 on the /hadoopstorage directory (which as you can see below from the conf files, is where the namenode files are located), so hadoop should have the ability to modify it.

Here is the namenode log file:

```
2013-11-26 16:51:25,951 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = <my machine>
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.2.1
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.2 -r 1503152; compiled by 'mattf' on Mon Jul 22 15:23:09 PDT 2013
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.6.0_65
************************************************************/
2013-11-26 16:51:26,187 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2013-11-26 16:51:26,203 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2013-11-26 16:51:26,204 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2013-11-26 16:51:26,204 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system started
2013-11-26 16:51:26,569 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2013-11-26 16:51:26,585 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2013-11-26 16:51:26,623 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source jvm registered.
2013-11-26 16:51:26,625 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source NameNode registered.
2013-11-26 16:51:26,711 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: Computing capacity for map BlocksMap
2013-11-26 16:51:26,711 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
2013-11-26 16:51:26,712 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: 2.0% max memory = 1039859712
2013-11-26 16:51:26,712 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
2013-11-26 16:51:26,712 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: recommended=2097152, actual=2097152
2013-11-26 16:51:26,740 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner=williammurphy
2013-11-26 16:51:26,740 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup=supergroup
2013-11-26 16:51:26,740 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled=true
2013-11-26 16:51:26,755 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=100
2013-11-26 16:51:26,755 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isAccessTokenEnabled=false accessKeyUpdateInterval=0 min(s), accessTokenLifetime=0 min(s)
2013-11-26 16:51:26,997 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Registered FSNamesystemStateMBean and NameNodeMXBean
2013-11-26 16:51:27,070 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: dfs.namenode.edits.toleration.length = 0
2013-11-26 16:51:27,070 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times 
2013-11-26 16:51:27,092 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Start loading image file /hadoopstorage/name/current/fsimage
2013-11-26 16:51:27,092 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Number of files = 1
2013-11-26 16:51:27,099 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Number of files under construction = 0
2013-11-26 16:51:27,099 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Image file /hadoopstorage/name/current/fsimage of size 119 bytes loaded in 0 seconds.
2013-11-26 16:51:27,100 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Start loading edits file /hadoopstorage/name/current/edits
2013-11-26 16:51:27,100 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: EOF of /hadoopstorage/name/current/edits, reached end of edit log Number of transactions found: 0.  Bytes read: 4
2013-11-26 16:51:27,100 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Start checking end of edit log (/hadoopstorage/name/current/edits) ...
2013-11-26 16:51:27,100 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Checked the bytes after the end of edit log (/hadoopstorage/name/current/edits):
2013-11-26 16:51:27,100 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog:   Padding position  = -1 (-1 means padding not found)
2013-11-26 16:51:27,100 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog:   Edit log length   = 4
2013-11-26 16:51:27,100 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog:   Read length       = 4
2013-11-26 16:51:27,101 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog:   Corruption length = 0
2013-11-26 16:51:27,101 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog:   Toleration length = 0 (= dfs.namenode.edits.toleration.length)
2013-11-26 16:51:27,104 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Summary: |---------- Read=4 ----------|-- Corrupt=0 --|-- Pad=0 --|
2013-11-26 16:51:27,104 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Edits file /hadoopstorage/name/current/edits of size 4 edits # 0 loaded in 0 seconds.
2013-11-26 16:51:27,106 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Image file /hadoopstorage/name/current/fsimage of size 119 bytes saved in 0 seconds.
2013-11-26 16:51:27,187 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: closing edit log: position=4, editlog=/hadoopstorage/name/current/edits
2013-11-26 16:51:27,189 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: close success: truncate to 4, editlog=/hadoopstorage/name/current/edits
2013-11-26 16:51:27,244 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameCache: initialized with 0 entries 0 lookups
2013-11-26 16:51:27,244 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Finished loading FSImage in 520 msecs
2013-11-26 16:51:27,246 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.safemode.threshold.pct          = 0.9990000128746033
2013-11-26 16:51:27,250 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.min.datanodes = 0
2013-11-26 16:51:27,250 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.safemode.extension              = 30000
2013-11-26 16:51:27,251 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Number of blocks excluded by safe block count: 0 total blocks: 0 and thus the safe blocks: 0
2013-11-26 16:51:27,268 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Total number of blocks = 0
2013-11-26 16:51:27,268 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Number of invalid blocks = 0
2013-11-26 16:51:27,268 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Number of under-replicated blocks = 0
2013-11-26 16:51:27,268 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Number of  over-replicated blocks = 0
2013-11-26 16:51:27,268 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* Safe mode termination scan for invalid, over- and under-replicated blocks completed in 17 msec
2013-11-26 16:51:27,268 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* Leaving safe mode after 0 secs
2013-11-26 16:51:27,269 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* Network topology has 0 racks and 0 datanodes
2013-11-26 16:51:27,269 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* UnderReplicatedBlocks has 0 blocks
2013-11-26 16:51:27,283 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: ReplicateQueue QueueProcessingStatistics: First cycle completed 0 blocks in 1 msec
2013-11-26 16:51:27,283 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: ReplicateQueue QueueProcessingStatistics: Queue flush completed 0 blocks in 1 msec processing time, 1 msec clock time, 1 cycles
2013-11-26 16:51:27,284 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: InvalidateQueue QueueProcessingStatistics: First cycle completed 0 blocks in 0 msec
2013-11-26 16:51:27,284 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: InvalidateQueue QueueProcessingStatistics: Queue flush completed 0 blocks in 0 msec processing time, 0 msec clock time, 1 cycles
2013-11-26 16:51:27,284 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.HostsFileReader: Refreshing hosts (include/exclude) list
2013-11-26 16:51:27,291 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source FSNamesystemMetrics registered.
2013-11-26 16:51:27,311 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: ReplicationMonitor thread received InterruptedExceptionjava.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
2013-11-26 16:51:27,312 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Number of transactions: 0 Total time for transactions(ms): 0 Number of transactions batched in Syncs: 0 Number of syncs: 0 SyncTimes(ms): 0 
2013-11-26 16:51:27,312 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DecommissionManager: Interrupted Monitor
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DecommissionManager$Monitor.run(DecommissionManager.java:65)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
2013-11-26 16:51:27,312 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: closing edit log: position=4, editlog=/hadoopstorage/name/current/edits
2013-11-26 16:51:27,314 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: close success: truncate to 4, editlog=/hadoopstorage/name/current/edits
2013-11-26 16:51:27,321 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:124)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.bind(Server.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener.<init>(Server.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.<init>(Server.java:1539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.<init>(RPC.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getServer(RPC.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1488)
```

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:23</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
  <value>/hadoopstorage/name/</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property> 
<name>mapred.job.tracker</name> 
<value>localhost:22</value> 
</property>
</configuration>
```

If anyone has encountered a similar error or can shed some light on the situation, it would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to start the Hadoop services on [privileged ports](http://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html) (< 1024). In particular you're trying to start the Job Tracker on port 22, which is the [well-known port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) for SSH. You should avoid binding to well-known ports for other applications.

You could check if this is the case by running `start-all.sh` as root. It that fixes it you could continue to run as root (generally a bad idea), or reconfigure to use higher numbered ports:

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
     <property>
         <name>fs.default.name</name>
         <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
     </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
     <property>
         <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
         <value>localhost:9001</value>
     </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yep, I reconfigured it to run on 9022 and 9023 and the NameNode works just fine. Thanks!